# How do I find out a field's type information for a 'record' in appmaker in Server script?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to create a re-usable script for capturing record changes onSave with Server-side scripting.  To do that, I need the model information for a given table, including what type each field is.

I have figured out how to get the model for my table and details for the fields:

```
var table = "Clients";
var myObject = app.models[table];
// Dump the properties of the 2nd field in the model
console.log("Field 2 properties: " + JSON.stringify(myObject["L"]["fields"]["1"]));
```

I see this:

```
{"name":"Client",
"key":"zzzkS1spSPKkRXMn",
"displayName":null,
"description":"Short name for client (must be unique)",
"type":{},
"required":false,
"uid":false,
"defaultValue":null,
"minLength":0,
"maxLength":null,
"integer":false,
"sortable":true,
"minValue":null,
"maxValue":null,
"regexp":null,
"regexpError":null,
"possibleValues":null,
"aggregationType":null
}
```

"type" looks like an empty property here and I can't seem to figure out how to get any reference to it to tell me what I need.

How do I get usable type information for a given field in a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, App Maker doesn't expose an API to access the model metadata.
You snippet is actually accessing App Maker's internal state and might break in future releases (the "L" property is actually obfuscated by a JS compiler and not designed to be accessed from user land).

We know this kind of meta-programming is handy and this is something we might add in the future based on user feedback. Please feel free to submit a request feature in our issue tracker (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/support).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've added the request to the issue tracker.